# App freeze after typing first char in search bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tableview, searchbar

I implemented a searchbar in a table view. Every thing was ok. For customizing reasons I did embed both in a view controller. Since this point the App freeze after typing the first char into the search bar. Pausing/unpausing the app after that shows different points in debuger, so the app seems to be running and in the display I can see the char I typed highlited (bigger) on the keyboard. After playing around a bit I found out that, when I first time select the search bar, but do not type anything and hit cancel, this fixes the problem. After this I can use the search bar as expected.

I searched the internet for some days, but didn't found any hints to solve this problem. So any help is welcome.

here my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

[super viewDidLoad];

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PhaseHintergrund"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
self.searchItem = nil;

[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Suchleiste"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Symptomsuche";
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavbarTransparent"];
searchBar.backgroundImage = myImage;
searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.separatorColor = self.tableView.separatorColor;
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
[self.tableView reloadData];

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;

-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UITextView *symptom = (UITextView*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
symptom.text = (NSString*)[object valueForKey:@"name"];

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)_controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString 

self.searchItem = searchString;
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
return YES;

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)_controller willUnloadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 

self.searchItem = nil;
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**Edit**
Setting breakpoints in all UISearchDisplayController delegate methods, I found out that in the case of error (first time using the searchbar without cancel before) the method searchDisplayController: didLoadSearchResultsTableView: will not be executed. So it seems to me, that there is no active tableview at this time, which probably leads to the problem/error.

So the question is what I am missing or doing wrong in the initialisation, that canceling the search is fixing for me ?

Comment: What does Instruments show you?  Run the time profiler and see what is happening.

Comment: time profiler is showing 1/4 of the bar height. I supose this means on my quadcore, that one core is on full load.

Comment: and look at the data below the bar (bottom half of the screen).  What code is being run?

Comment: after 2.5 min of running it shows that my app consumed 75% of the time

Comment: Doing **WHAT**? The time profiler is not just a graph.  There is data at the bottom of the screen that tells you what code is being run.  What code is being run?  Or add a screenshot of Instruments running.

Comment: seems that I can't attach pictures for now, so here the link [link](http://www.moninet.de/pics/timeProfilerRun.png)

Comment: Now hide system libraries and it will show you where in your code you are taking up all that time.  Eliminate that.

Comment: Hiding the system librarys, shows that the system librarys are taking all the time [link](http://www.moninet.de/pics/timeProfilerRun2.png) right ?

Comment: Hiding the system libraries will show where in your code you are taking up all the time.  It also helps to check the invert stack button.  That will highlight where in your code the issue exists.

Comment: That all was clear to me, but as you can see in the second screenshot, the time is used outside my code in the system librarys. Also note my edited post.

Comment: Can you invert the call tree and post another image?  That will help us identify the issue.

Comment: Of course: [link](http://www.moninet.de/pics/timeProfilerRun3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a workaround for my problem, but still don't understand why it is working now. In viewDidLoad I added the following line after the initialization:

```
    [self searchDisplayController:self.searchController didLoadSearchResultsTableView:self.searchController.searchResultsTableView];
```

Now the Searchbar is also working for the first search.

Answer (score 1):

Every single time `-searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` gets called, you’re making a new fetched results controller and reloading your table view. You’re likely doing that way too often for performance.